# Send Location to Google Form on boot (how to run MainActivity on Boot)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-forms

So I'm pretty much a beginner with Android Studio, but I'm almost there. My goal is to transfer the longitude, latitude and some other data to a form on google. It works when I press the button (button2), but I want it to start the activity to send data on boot. So I got a bootreceiver, but it only starts the application but not the activity to send data. Hope someone can help me out. If something is unclear, please ask.

MyService.java:

```
package com.test.example.phonelocationnew;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service
{
@Override
public void onCreate(){

}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

BootReceiver.java:

```
package com.test.example.phonelocationnew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.test.example.phonelocationnew;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    public static final MediaType FORM_DATA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    //URL derived from form URL
    public static final String URL = "URL";
    //input element ids found from the live form page
    public static final String LAT="entry_1903202747";
    public static final String LONG="entry_1549783406";
    public static final String MOD="entry_1161588883";
    public static final String MAN="entry_852582911";
    public static final String IMEI="entry_738564261";
    public static final String EXIP="entry_1256979126";
    public static final String ACC="entry_1601482207";


    private Context context;

    LocationManager locationmanager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        context=this;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        final TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        final TextView textView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        final TextView textView14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        final TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        final TextView textView15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);



        locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria cri = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri, false);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
        }

        if (provider != null & !provider.equals("")) {
            Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 30000, 0, this); //original (provider,minimalTime,minimalDistance,this); (provider,1800000,0,this) = 30 minutes; 0 distance change

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        TextView textView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        TextView textView14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        TextView textView15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);


        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String strLat="LA "+location.getLatitude();
        String strLong="LO "+location.getLongitude();
        String strAcc=""+location.getAccuracy();
        String strMod=""+ Build.MODEL;
        String strMan=""+ Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String strId=""+ mngr.getDeviceId();

        try{
            URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

            String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
            String strIp =""+ip;
            textView7.setText(strIp);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            textView7.setText("ERROR");
        }

        textView3.setText(strLat);
        textView5.setText(strLong);
        textView12.setText(strMod);
        textView13.setText(strMan);
        textView14.setText(strId);
        textView15.setText(strAcc);

        final PostDataTask postDataTask = new PostDataTask();
        postDataTask.execute(URL, textView3.getText().toString(), textView5.getText().toString(), textView12.getText().toString(), textView13.getText().toString(), textView14.getText().toString(), textView7.getText().toString(), textView15.getText().toString());

    }

    //Start Service
    public void startService(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    //Stop Service
    public void stopService(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle){
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s){
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s){
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }

    //AsyncTask to send data as a http POST request
    private class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contactData) {

            Boolean result = true;
            String url = contactData[0];
            String LATs = contactData[1];

            String LONGs = contactData[2];
            String modS = contactData[3];
            String manS = contactData[4];
            String idS = contactData[5];
            String ipS = contactData[6];
            String accS = contactData[7];

            String postBody="";

            try {
                //all values must be URL encoded to make sure that special characters like & | ",etc.
                //do not cause problems
                postBody = LAT + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(LATs,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + LONG + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(LONGs,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + MOD + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(modS,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + MAN + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(manS,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + IMEI + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(idS,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + EXIP + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ipS,"UTF-8") +
                        "&" + ACC + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(accS,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                result=false;
            }

            try{
                //Create OkHttpClient for sending request
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                //Create the request body with the help of Media Type
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(FORM_DATA_TYPE, postBody);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                //Send the request
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            }catch (IOException exception){
                result=false;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            //Print Success or failure message accordingly
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(1800000);
//            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
//                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
//            }
            Toast.makeText(context,result?"Message successfully sent!":"There was some error in sending message. Please try again after some time.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.example.phonelocationnew" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-sdk  android:maxSdkVersion="21"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".MyService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#620606"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Latitude = "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="..." />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Longtitude = "
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="..." />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop Service"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="stopService"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:backgroundTint="#3b2525"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Service"
        android:onClick="startService"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:backgroundTint="#3b2525"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Model = "
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Manufacturer = "
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="IMEI = "
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView12" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="External/WIFI IP = "
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView14" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Accuracy (meter) = "
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So for a better understanding what I really want in my application, below an explanation:

**I want my MainActivity to run on boot of my Android device, so it will send the location data to the google form in the background everytime I start up my phone.**

Comment: Do you specify your launch activity in manifest file? Please provide us with your manifest file content

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll add it now!

Comment: Didn't understand your question. So you say it works when you press the `button2`? What is the `button2` `onClick()` method? If you want to do what is done after click when your activity starts, you simply need to do the same in your `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity` (ofc you should move these actions to some method to avoid duplicate code)

Comment: I want the application to send the location data (longtitude,latitude,etc.) to the google form when I startup my android phone WITHOUT pressing a single button. Currently the button2 = startService, so when I press the button the data will be send to the form (and it keeps doing this every 40-50s).

Comment: So I said what can you do to achieve that :)

Comment: Can you give an example ? Because I don't know exactly how to do it ... =S

Comment: If something happens when you click the button, this button has to have `onClick` event method with some actions (you can find it in Android Studio in layout viewer or maybe you define it programmatically - can't say with information you provided). You need to do the same actions in your `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity`. Can't provide any example, I don't code for Android usually.

Comment: Well I don't have an onClick event. See I have "Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);" (in MainActivity). Sorry its a bit vague,  I'm new with android studio/java.

Comment: Well something happen when you press this button right? So you just need to find, what exactly. Did you have your button in your xml markup? If so, you should be able to see method called on `onClick` event. See the picture: http://s.siliconimg.com/kb/content_images/2015/03/22/746554/1427038588_1.png

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the boot receiver, it starts your service correctly.

The problem is with your service, it doesn't do anything other than showing a toast. The actual data sending job is done by the MainActivity, everytime the location changes, whether you tap button2 to start the service or not, and it will continue even if you tap on button to stop the service, because, again, the service doesn't do anything.

What you need to do is move the part of the code that sends the data from your MainActivity to the service.

Also, an app like that is going to be an excellent battery killer. I would reduce the frequency of the data to get only what is really significant for you.

Something like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Here you get lat and long
        try {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //You have your latitude and longitude data
        //They are stored in the respective variables
        //Start an AsyncTask to send them wherever you want
        //You could adapt the one in your MainActivity here
        //Or create a different and separate class


        //Here you set an alarm to start the service again in ~15 minutes
        int minutesApart = 15;
        Intent repeat = new Intent(MyService.this, MyService.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MyService.this, 0, repeat, 0);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + minutesApart * 1000, alarmIntent);    

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to do is create the AsyncTask method to send the latitude and longitude.

P.s. This service can only be stopped by the OS when the memory is low (and it will start again when some memory is freed), and by pressing the 'button' from your MainActivity.

Comment: But what do you mean with adapting the AsyncTask in MainAcitivy? What needs to be adapted ?

Comment: @Y.Terz :

Cleaning it a little and do some test to make sure it works, which I could not do of course.
I.e. in your activity you get the lat/lon, set them as text in your textviews, and then get the text from there in order to pass them in the AsyncTask. Here you should simply pass the strLat/strLon value. Same for strMod, strMan, strId and strAcc (and you have to create them in the service).

Comment: I still dont really understand how to do it, I'm still really a noob at this... If I have the MyService you created and I still need the AsyncTask, can I just copy it from my MainActivity to MyService? If so, do I need to remove it from the MainActivity?

Comment: @Y.Terz
Yes, you can copy your AsyncTask, but you have to create the Strings to give to it in your service first, or you'll get an ArrayOutOfBoundException.
Try to understand your own code, when you see:
`postDataTask.execute(URL, textView3.getText().toString(), ...);`
you are passing the value of your textviews as a string to the AsyncTask. You can't do that in the service or you'll get an NPE, so you have to create those same strings (as you do in MainActivity), and pass them to the AsyncTask without setting them as text of the textviews first.
It's Cut-Paste, but you have to know what.

Comment: Well, the service works now when I open the application. It sends data without pressing a button. I simplified the postDataTask, for my own sake. But it still doesn't send data when I boot the phone. Also the accuracy is worse with your method, guess because you use the GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: @Y.Terz

Use the log to understand if is a problem of the BroadcastReceiver or the Service, one of them doesn't start properly.

Also try to add `android:enabled="true"` to the declaration of the receiver in the manifest (right below `android:name=".BootReceiver"`)

Comment: The weird thing is, it starts the application on boot ánd MyService is running, but still doesn't send data.

Comment: @Y.Terz maybe it crashes, check the logcat

Comment: Will do. But how do I use my original "getting location" method (more accurate) in MyService? I tried to put the original method from the MainActivity in the place of your method with GPS provider, but it has something to do with Activity, because keep getting an error at the ActivityCompat.requestPermission(this...): Wrong first argument type 'com.test.example.phonelocationnew.MyService', required 'android.app.Activity'.